# Loading an image based on browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```
<img class="abc" src="abc.jpg"/>
<img class="xyz" src="xyz.jpg"/>
<script>
  if (window.innerWidth > 500)
    {
        $(".abc").remove();
    }
    else 
    {
        $(".xyz").remove();
    }
</script>
```

But it only hides the image, i guess. Because the network tab shows the page size total to the size of both the images.

Comment: It's being removed from the DOM.  The network tab shows how much data was loaded - as you're `remove()`ing the image after it's been loaded, the network tab would show both.  You *could* put the `<img>` tags inside a `document.write` inside the `if`.  Or you could set the `src=` inside the if.

Comment: What happens if the user resizes after the page has loaded?

Comment: A better alternative would be to use `css` `@media` and show/hide `.abc` `.xyz` based on screen width that way.

Comment: @freedomn-m Hide just hide the image. It will still make the user load the image, and therefore decrease website speed

Comment: @Toby in your example you allready starting the requests for both images. Even if you remove the `image-tag` the user still loads the image. You can add the `src` with: `$(".abc").src = "example.com"`. Than only one Image is loaded. The other needs to be hidden. Problem: User-Resize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only to complete this thread, you could also try the HTML `picture` Tag.

```
<picture class="abcxyz">
     <source srcset="abc.jpg" media="(max-width: 499px)">
     <img src="xyz.jpg" alt="xyz">
</picture>
```

But be careful. IE does not support this solution.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) for more informations.

## Update

If you need to added classes to that picture-element you could do it like this:

```
<style>
    .abcxyz {
        outline:2px solid lightblue;
    }

    @media (min-width:500px) {
        .abcxyz {
            outline:2px solid black;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: IE is outdated, no one use it. Edge is the future. So this is the best method, i guess? Since no JS required = Better Speed + Responsive on browser width change without reloading the page?

Comment: Can i use class inside both image tags? Can you show me how?

Comment: @Toby A pagereload is not needed.

Comment: Yeah. But i want to know, how to use class in <source> tag, can you tell me please?

Comment: @Toby I'm not sure what you want to achieve but I've added an example for how to work with CSS classes. Hope this helps.

Comment: it's crazy solution(

Answer (score 2):

### css solution

You doesn't need js to achieve it, you could use css media inquiries to do that, like below.

```css
img.abc {display:block;}
img.xyz {display:none;}

@media (min-width:500px) {
  img.abc {display:none;}
  img.xyz {display:block;}
}
```

```html
<img class="abc" src="abc.jpg" alt="abc"/>
<img class="xyz" src="xyz.jpg" alt="xyz"/>
```

### Make JS from stop loading both the images

The browser will load any images that has a `src` attribute set, so what you want to do is to use `data-src` in the markup and use JavaScript to set the `src` attribute like below:

```js
var abc = $(".abc").data("src"),
   abc_alt = $(".abc").data("alt"),
   xyz = $(".xyz").data("src"),
   xyz_alt = $(".xyz").data("alt");

if (window.innerWidth > 500) {
    $(".xyz").attr("src",xyz);
    $(".xyz").attr("alt",xyz_alt);
} else {
    $(".abc").attr("src",abc);
    $(".abc").attr("alt",abc_alt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="abc" data-src="abc.jpg" data-alt="abc">
<img class="xyz" data-src="xyz.jpg" data-alt="xyz">
```

Comment: It will still load both the images. Any way make JS from stop loading both the images?

Comment: @Toby Please see my supplementary answers, if it works for you, please accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry but Kamal's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```js
if (window.innerWidth > 500)
{
    $(".abc").attr("src", "abc.jpg");
}
    
else 
{
    $(".abc").attr("src", "xyz.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<img class="abc" src=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JS, try this

```
<img class="abc" src="abc.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
<img class="xyz" src="xyz.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
<script>
    if (window.innerWidth > 500){
        $(".abc").hide();
        $(".xyz").show();
    } else {
        $(".abc").show();
        $(".xyz").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That will probably still load both images, though

Comment: @Pekka웃 make snippet with your code and we'll try to help you